# How to authenticate user against on-premise ADFS

Tags: c#, .net, adfs, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a desktop application (Winforms) that has to use ADFS (on-premis) to authenticate users.

Is it possible just to authenticate a user (check if login/password is correct)? How?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/) but change the metadata address to use ADFS rather than AAD.